# Как хранить токены и пароли, которые необходимы для работы приложения?

Tags: php, архитектура

Приветствую. Мне в приложении, например, нужно обращаться к базе, а значит нужно как-то получать и хранить логин, пароль для базы; нужно обращаться к `API vk` и для этого хранить токены. Также приложение должно иметь возможность менять эти токены/пароли. Написать эти пароли прямо в коде - тоже не лучший вариант.

Как это правильно сделать с точки зрения архитектуры? Конечно, можно просто хранить всё в каком-нибудь `json` файле, но корректно ли так делать? Может стоит написать статический класс `AccountsManager`, который будет всеми этими делами управлять?

Comment: Вы можете хранить их в закодированном виде и раскодировать "на лету" по паролю из ини-файла или введенного вручную

Comment: Обычно это делается ограничением доступа к местоположению этих данных так, чтобы только приложение могло читать и писать их (и соответственно администратор приложения). Не обязательно закодировывать их, нужно ограничить доступ к файлу или месту где они хранятся.

Comment: @DNS, серьёзно? Тратить драгоценное время ответа на расшифровку конфига?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких вещей существует [DotEnv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv).
Все ключи хранятся в ini-подобном файле `.env` в корневой папке проекта. Но чтобы в git не загружали секретные данные, в ту же папку можно положить `.env.example`, в котором будет шаблон настроек, который нужно переименовать или скопировать в `.env`. Доступ к ключам будет через `getenv` функцию. `// Очень удобно, сам пользуюсь подобным подходом`

Можно еще более заморочиться, если вы крупная компания. Продукт, называемый [Vault от HashiCorp](https://www.vaultproject.io/) призванный централизованно хранить ключи и токены. Сам пока что не использовал, но выглядит интересно.

## ВАЖНО!

Секретные ключи никогда не должны быть доступны другим. Поэтому вшивать их в код, заливать в систему контроля версий и п.р. категорически не рекомендуется. Настройки должны лежать там, где используются, а именно на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Храни данные от базы в .php файле и подключай его через include.

```
return [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'schema' => 'db_name',
    #Дальше сам
];
```

В бд храни данные от акков: Логин, пароль, текущий токен.

Answer (score 1):

Есть много вариантов (xml, json, txt файлы), и по сути каждый не плох, предложу вариант, который больше всего мне симпатичен, пишется класс для хранения настроек:

```
class Config
{
    static private $params = [];

    public static function get($key)
    {
        return isset(self::$params[$key]) ? self::$params[$key] : false;
    }

    public static function set($key,$value)
    {
        self::$params[$key] = $value;
    }


    public function __get($key)
    {
        return isset(self::$params[$key]) ? self::$params[$key] : false;
    }

    public function __isset($key)
    {
        return isset(self::$params[$key]);
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
Config::set("db_host", "localhost");
Config::set("db_port", 5432);

Config::get("db_host");
```

кстати, можно данный класс привязать к файлу